# How can I display data from two unrelated tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two unrelated tables in a MYSQL database. I want to select and display data from both of them.

As an example, the tables looks like this:
[image: separate tables]

I would like to display the results on my site, organised alphabetically, like this:
[image: results table]

The ID from each table is used to refer to a photo of the cat or dog. I haven't had much luck with JOIN statements, would a UNION work in this scenario?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You would need a `join`. Edit your question and add the `join` statement you tried.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing There's nothing related JOIN here.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing How can you join unrelated tables?

Comment: Side note: You *probably* should consider re-modeling your data.  You have two tables storing essentially the same thing and the `Alpha` column looks like it's just a repeat of data that's already in the `Name` column.

Comment: @David Thanks, I have a lot more columns in the real tables and it wouldn't suit to remodel for other reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Alpha, Name, CONVERT(Cat_Id, CHAR(50)) AS Cat_Id, '' AS Dog_Id
FROM Cat
UNION ALL
SELECT Alpha, Name, '' AS Cat_Id, CONVERT(Dog_Id, CHAR(50)) AS Dog_Id
FROM Dog
ORDER BY Alpha
```

A few comments:

Strictly speaking, if we want to show empty string for missing cat or dog IDs, then we need to cast the `Cat_Id` or `Dog_Id` columns to `CHAR`, because all values in a column need to be the same type.

It is not necessary to wrap the `UNION` query to use `ORDER BY` and sort by the `Alpha` column, rather we can just add `ORDER BY` to the end.

Comment: This worked well. As there are other columns in both tables I used UNION, instead of UNION ALL. I wasn't aware of casting the values like that, many thanks.

Comment: @ovokuro I believe that in MySQL you can get away without the cast.  But other more strict databases, such as SQL Server, might not allow it, so it's a good habit to have.

Comment: As Tim Biegeleisen stated it will be a good habit to use cast. @ovokuro, if you use UNION ALL you will allow mysql to skip comparison for two sets for uniqueness. Union removes duplicate rows. In this case UNION All will improve performance in long run when data will increase.

Comment: @AshokM.Prajapati - Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Alpha,Name,Cat_ID,'' as Dog_ID
FROM Cat
UNION ALL
SELECT Alpha,Name,'' as Cat_ID,Dog_ID
FROM Dog
```

Answer (score 1):

I would combine the two tables into one table using the fields:

```
ID   Type   Name   Alpha
```

The type field would be either cat or dog then the rest will fill in as you have. This also allows you to add additional animal types in the future without having to change your database. Then it is a simple select when displaying your data.